# Convert URL generated from createObjectURL to base64

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

What is the best way to convert the URL generated from the function `createObjectURL` back to base64.

```
 let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
 console.log(url)
```

The above code generates a URL like this

```
blob:https://s.codepen.io/d3e427c6-9aee-4f07-957c-3c928ff713c2
```

The only way I know to convert it back to an actual blob or base64 is by using `fetch` to make an call to the same URL like below

```
fetch(window.URL.createObjectURL(file))
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => console.log(blob)
```

Personally, I don't like the above approach, but I have been unsuccessful in finding alternate ways to do it. Are there ?

Comment: Do you have to use `createObjectURL`? Do you have access to the actual file so you can read it as base64 and avoid this call? `createObjectURL` is tricky and prone to memory leaks since if you do not close the document or clean up with `revokeObjectURL`

Comment: @Akrion Yeah, I am working with Redux and want to avoid storing the huge base64 data in the store, because I would be having lots of images to store

Comment: The thing is you are getting a string from a file so you have to get to the file from the string to get the Base64 so unless you keep a reference somewhere to that file/base64 you have to go get it again. If you are getting the files via function maybe cache via lodash `_.memoize` or similar so that function output is cached ...

Comment: A blob URL only exists until the document is reloaded. There's rarely a need to store it anywhere.